# Keda AzureMonitor trigger giving no activeDirectoryClientId given error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, keda, azure-monitor, keda-scaledjob

I was trying to configure Azure Monitor Scaler for keda autoscaling. In my scaled object I have specified the Clientid and password for the application. In the Azure portal as well, I can see the clientid , password and tenantid . But after deploying the scaledobject , I'm getting error on keda operator like no activeDirectoryClientId given. I don't know what went wrong. Can anyone please help me here?

Below is keda-operator logs:

```
ERROR controllers.ScaledObject Failed to ensure HPA is correctly created for ScaledObject {"ScaledObject.Namespace": "xxxx", "ScaledObject.Name": "azure-monitor-keda-scaledobject", "error": "error getting scaler for trigger #0: error parsing azure monitor metadata: no activeDirectoryClientId given"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).reconcileHandler
/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.6.5/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:244
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem
/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.6.5/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:218
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).worker
/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.6.5/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:197
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil.func1
/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.20.4/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:155
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil
/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.20.4/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:156
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil
/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.20.4/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.Until
/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.20.4/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:90
2021-08-03T11:41:27.230Z ERROR controller Reconciler error {"reconcilerGroup": "keda.sh", "reconcilerKind": "ScaledObject", "controller": "scaledobject", "name": "azure-monitor-keda-scaledobject", "namespace": "xxxx", "error": "error getting scaler for trigger #0: error parsing azure monitor metadata: no activeDirectoryClientId given"}
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).processNextWorkItem
/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.6.5/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:218
sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime/pkg/internal/controller.(*Controller).worker
/go/pkg/mod/sigs.k8s.io/controller-runtime@v0.6.5/pkg/internal/controller/controller.go:197
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil.func1
/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.20.4/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:155
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.BackoffUntil
/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.20.4/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:156
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.JitterUntil
/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.20.4/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:133
k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/util/wait.Until
/go/pkg/mod/k8s.io/apimachinery@v0.20.4/pkg/util/wait/wait.go:90
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include the trigger authentication code? if not you need to include trigger authentication code in scaled object please check this [reference](https://keda.sh/docs/2.3/scalers/azure-monitor/#example)